# When the user_link permission is requested from Facebook, GraphRequest.newMeRequest() returns a null object

Tags: facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I'm letting Firebase handle login to Facebook in my app, as advised in the Firebase docs:

```
        loginButton.setPermissions("email", "public_profile");
```

When I call GraphRequest.newMeRequest(), I request the user_link permission as follows:

```
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                // Need special permission from Faceook in order to get this data. Apply after we've settled on a new name for the app.
                parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email, gender, birthday, timezone, picture, locale, user_link, age_range");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
```

But when GraphRequest.newMeRequest() completes, it returns a null object. This doesn't happen if I leave out user_link in my permissions request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I call GraphRequest.newMeRequest(), I request the user_link permission as follows

You are not requesting permissions there, you are requesting fields.

And the field is named `link`, not `user_link`.

You need to request the *permission* with `loginButton.setPermissions`, and then request the field by its correct name.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!

Comment: After Facebook approves my request for `user_link` permission, how do I get the user's profile link ? the `link` field already returns a value for a friend's profile link (without the `user_link` permission being approved by Facebook) on the form of: `https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxx` where `xxxx` is a timed token that expires after some period of time which then invalidates the link.

Comment: @JAHelia yes, and that URL is what you are supposed to use to link to the user profile. You don't get anything else any more.

Comment: @CBroe I submitted my app for Facebook review to get a permission for `user_link`, because getting a timed-token link is unreasonable in my use case, as I let the user to link his Facebook page with his profile in my app, that means, after the token in the user link expires, the link won't work.

Comment: Yes, and that is absolutely intended. Submitting your app for review will not change anything - you won't get anything else but such a tokenized URL.