# Getting "Content not found" error when following app-scoped user ID

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

Thanks again to Cbroe who answered [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60614008/when-the-user-link-permission-is-requested-from-facebook-graphrequest-newmerequ). I implemented his suggestion and although the URL returned by GraphRequest.newMeRequest looks valid, when I followed it, I got a "Content not found" error:

```
        reachOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Navigate to person's Facebook page to send a message.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(linkArray[selectedPosition]));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

BTW, in the above, I did confirm that linkArray[selectedPosition] contained the correct value.

[image]

I had previously (back in 2018!) successfully completed an app review for user_link, so I doubt that that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to resubmit my app for approval because now it's working again.